# ASP.net enabling gzip - not working

Tags: asp.net, gzip

First to note, I have all permissions by my host. I don't have access to IIS right now, so I need to enable gzip compression in web.config file or any other way. I need to enable it for js, css, images and html. This is my entire web.config now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect to WWW" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-    9]+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
 <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*localhost.*" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*stage\..*" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*dev\..*" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
 <httpCompression>
<scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
<dynamicTypes>
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
</dynamicTypes>
<staticTypes>
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
</staticTypes>
 </httpCompression>
 <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
 </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

This is my application.host at this time (I'm aware it is probably incorrect):

```
    <system.webServer>
         <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files"
            staticCompressionDisableCpuUsage="95" staticCompressionEnableCpuUsage="60"
            dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage="95" dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="50">
            <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
            <dynamicTypes>
              <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
              <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
            </dynamicTypes>
            <staticTypes>
              <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
              <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
            </staticTypes>
          </httpCompression>
          <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
        </system.webServer>
```

And these are my headers:

```
0 >>>>>> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type >>>>>> text/html
Last-Modified >>>>>> Tue, 22 Nov 2016 11:26:11 GMT
Accept-Ranges >>>>>> bytes
ETag >>>>>> "5773883ab344d21:0"
Server >>>>>> Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By >>>>>> ASP.NET
Date >>>>>> Tue, 22 Nov 2016 12:16:09 GMT
Connection >>>>>> close
Content-Length >>>>>> 17831
```

Also, to note, when checking site at google pagespeed sometimes it says gzip is enabled, than sometimes it is not. What is proper way to enable it? Please do not post other solutions from stackoverflow, I have tried everything for last few days, and I just can't worked it out

Comment: Can you verify that the application pool is using integrated mode? Otherwise the above code won't work.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick how do I check that? It's not my project, so only access I have is via ftp

Comment: Unfortunately you really can't without access to IIS since that's the only real way you can check application pools.